# Preventing 'Jump to top" links

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have used this in my footer.php to prevent tooltip links I have from jumping to the top of the page,however by using this it also deactivates / breaks my navigation bar?

Is there a way to use this to prevent the 'jump to top' on tooltip buttons, but still keep the navigation bar from being effected?

```
<script>
jQuery( "a" ).click(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $( "<div>" )
    .append( "default " + event.type + " prevented" )
    .appendTo( "#log" );
});
</script>
```

[Link](http://i-b-a.co.za)

You will see icons on the page representing "wifi" "bathrooms" etc.  The below was used so that those tooltip links (#) do not make the page jump when clicked

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to do the trick

```
<script>
 jQuery( 'a[href="#"]' ).click(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $( "<div>" )
  .append( "default " + event.type + " prevented" )
  .appendTo( "#log" );


});
</script>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity why are you wrapping those in a tags to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

add **return false** as the last line of your function

```
<script>
 jQuery( "a" ).click(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $( "<div>" )
  .append( "default " + event.type + " prevented" )
  .appendTo( "#log" );

  return false;

});
</script>
```

Comment: I added "return false" the tooltip links are deactivated which is correct, but my navigation bar still won't work